# Load testing in Visual studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, load-testing, performance-testing

I donwloaded trail version of Visual studio ultimate 2010. I created a unit test to test a wcf service. Now when I click the project to add a load test, I dont see the Web Performance test and Load test options. I only see Unit Test, Coded UI Test, Ordered Test and Generic Test. Can someone please let me know if I need do download something else?

Comment: could you explain a bit more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to download the service pack 1.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your application up and running, I suggest that you consider using Fiddler & Web Performance Test to generate load tests for your WCF service. With fiddler you can capture all HTTP traffic between your application and the WCF service and then export it into a web test. Web Tests have better integration with Load Tests in visual studio.

I also recommend that you download the Visual Studio Performance Testing (not so) Quick reference guide: http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/